# How can phpMyAdmin be restarted after /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php is changed?

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, phpmyadmin

How can phpMyAdmin (running on Ubuntu 10.04) be restarted after the `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file was changed?

Comment: I've never liked using a package manager for phpMyAdmin. I've always found it easier and faster to download directly form http://www.phpmyadmin.net/, copy the sample config file to config.inc.php, and edit that

Comment: What does this have to do with the question anyway? It's about how a change in the config file gets applied.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No need to restart phpMyAdmin, changes in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` are automatically applied.

Comment: so why when uncomment :$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
I get still message: Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

Comment: Are you using root account without password? And which version of PMA are you using?

Comment: i am using as root and 4.3.3

Comment: @Yosef: been there too. There are 2 lines in config file with this setting. I'm not sure which one needs to be uncommented, but if you do just one - 50% chance is that's the wrong one unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar situation on Ubuntu 10.10 (phpmyadmin 3.3.7deb3build0.10.10.1) and even after editing `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` I couldn't login (because of AllowNoPassword).

I had to `cp /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.sample.inc.php /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` and then add the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;` line to it.

It is strange, but it worked.

Comment: The same issue with me. It seems that Ubuntu ignores `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` but loads `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. Uncomment "Storage database and tables" section and "Designer" mode will be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Try and open it using:

```
sudo gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Uncomment it and save, but keep it open - then try opening phpMyAdmin. It should work.